# CKEditor 5 in production environment

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

The guys from CKSource just launched the first version of CKEditor 5.

Is it safe to use it on a production environment? ( update the platform using it from 4.x to 5 ) or better to wait for the next minor versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading this answer please do mind that it might've got outdated with time.

First of all, check out the [Browser Compatibility](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/support/browser-compatibility.html) guide. It's a source of up to date information about the stability of CKEditor 5 on various browsers and environments.

Second of all, CKEditor 5 is a new product, designed and built from scratch. When migrating from CKEditor 4 to it you may find some features missing. You'll need to check that yourself. You can also check the [Migration from CKEditor 4 to CKEditor 5](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/migrate.html) guide.

Finally, we do generally recommend testing CKEditor 5 yourself. There's no point to upgrade CKEditor 4 to CKEditor 5 if you'd miss something in it.

tl;dr: CKEditor 5 is production ready for specific use cases. To know if it's ready for you, test it :)